# Navigating between <div> elements of same page using AngularJS with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and angular js to develope a single page application.

I have the page like,

```
                First | Second
```

My code goes like this,

```
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar">
              <div class="navbar-inner">               
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#first">First</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#second">Second</a></li>

                   </ul>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="first">this is first page</div>
            <div id="second">this is second page</div>                  
            </div>
```

But when I navigate through the buttons both HTML elements are getting displayed

```
<div id="first">this is first page</div>
                <div id="second">this is second page</div>
```

How to navigate properly.

Please Advice

Comment: What makes you think this is sufficient to make a single-page app?  As far as I know, Bootstrap doesn't do any kind of single-page stuff beyond one long scrolled page that you can nav to (which is what your code will do when you have enough content to scroll).  AngularJS may do more, but it looks like you'd need to add more Javascript to make it work.

Comment: @cincodenada: *(Regarding your edit suggestion)* I'm not sure about this particular case but generally it is unnecessary to add a keyword to the title if that keyword is already present in the tags.

Comment: @AndriyM Mkay, I'll keep that in mind.  In this case, I think this question has more to do with AngularJS than Bootstrap, so it didn't make sense to have Bootstrap in the title but not AngularJS, since it's a single-page app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide one div and show another you can use `ng-show` on your divs and use your buttons to show or hide your divs. some think like this:

```
$scope.showFirst = true;

<div id="first" ng-show="showFirst">this is first page</div>
<div id="second" ng-show="!showFirst">this is second page</div>
```

and use your buttons to toggle between `showFirst` property:

```
ng-click="showFirst = true" // On your first button
ng-click="showFirst = false" // On your second button
```

But if these divs are different pages, you must use routing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create CSS something like this: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/az6UV/2/)

```
.pageContainer {
    width:300px;
    height:300px; 
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.containInner {
    float:left;
    width:900px;
}

.pageContainer .page {
    width:300px;
    height:300px; 
    float:left;
}

#first {
    background:red;
}
#second {
    background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with angularJS and jquery as per below way.

## html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">               
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a id="first" ng-click="navigatePage(this)">First</a></li>
                <li><a id="second" ng-click="navigatePage(this);">Second</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="first">this is first page</div>
    <div id="second">this is second page</div>                  
</div>
```

## Angularjs

```
$scope.navigatePage = funntion(obj){
    var targetId = $(obj).attr('id');
    var scroT = $('#'+targetId).offset();
    $('html,body').stop(true,true).animate({scrollTop:scroT.top+'px'});
}
```